# Idiomatic way to say "You mistaken A for B and B for A"

Tags: phrases, expressions

For example there are two bones in the forearm: radius and ulna. Let's say I call radius ulna and call ulna radius, and you're going to point out my mistake. How would you succinctly express that?

Comment: *You confused A with B*.

Comment: You've got them switched.

Comment: A little vulgar, but maybe "_ass-backwards_"

Comment: You've got them backwards.

Comment: You've confused A and B with each other.